# unit test structure and import

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I want to know how to properly import file in my test file without using `__init__.py` in test root folder. Last sentence of [this artice](https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/directory_structure.html) states, that `test` directory should not have `init` file.

I don't know much about python so I would like to know: 
1) Why not
2) How to import file `tested.py` to the `test_main.py` in order to test its functionality without using `init` file as a script that insert paths to PYTHONPATHS? 
My project has a following structure

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── my
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── my_sub
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── tested.py
└── test
    └── test_main.py
```

Files contains following code

```
#/Python_test/__init__.py
import my.main

#/Python_test/my/__init__.py
#empty

#/Python_test/my/main.py
from .my_sub.tested import inc
print(inc(5))

#/Python_test/my/my_sub/__init__.py
#empty

#/Python_test/my/my_sub/tested.py
def inc(x):
    return x+1

#/Python_test/test/test_main.py
from Python_pytest.my.my_sub.tested import func
def test_answer():
    assert func(3) == 3
```

When I run the code from command line python `__init__.py` it prints 6, which is correct.

I would like to test the function `inc()` in `tested.py` file. 
 1. I installed `pytest` package as a testing framework,
 2. created test file similar to the one from tutorial [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#getstarted) called `test_main.py`.
 3. Added `__init__.py` with a code that finds path of the root directory and adds it to `sys.path`

It worked well but then I read that this shouldn't be done this way. But how should it be done? I have hard time reading some unit tested code from some github repositories that are tested and don't use the init file. (one of them is [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3/tree/develop/tests)) I can't find any clue that suggest how to properly use it.

I also tried to use relative imports this way

```
from ..my.main import func
```

but it throws `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package.` Which is ok. But I tried it anyway.

Now I don't know how to do that. Tutorials concerning importing usually states that we should add paths of imported modules to `sys.path` (if they are not present already) but how should I do that when there shouldn't be the `init` file which can hold the functionality?

Comment: The article you linked refers to an old version of `pytest`; I suggest you to rather take a look at [Good Integration Practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) showing project setups both with and without the `__init__.py` files.